# Where should i put my .jasper file and how to access it?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, war

I am developing Java web application using JSP and JasperReports for my reporting engine. And I'm using AWS ELB as application server.

I'm not sure where should i place my .jasper file and how to access it.

My project structure:

[image: How my project files looks like]

I have tried :

1. Making folder inside the Web folder and put the .jasper inside it. I access it with below code

```
String jasperPath = "\\report\\TestPengguna.jasper";
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperPath, new HashMap(), JConnectionUtil.con);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, response.getOutputStream());
```

2. Put the .jasper inside the Web folder and access it like this

```
String jasperPath = "\\TestPengguna2.jasper";
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperPath, new HashMap(), JConnectionUtil.con);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, response.getOutputStream());
```

3. Access it with this code

```
String jasperPath = "\\report\\TestPengguna.jasper";
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(cl.getResourceAsStream(jasperPath), new HashMap(), JConnectionUtil.con);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, response.getOutputStream());
```

UPDATED : Solve this using the link given by Alex K. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Problems to access a report in a jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4204183/876298) & [How to get jasperreport file (.JRXML) exact location to load to the system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38113179/876298)

Comment: Hi Alex K, Thanks a lot. My problem can be answered from the link you give.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of jasper files, is that they are compiled separate to your project, and can be edited in case of formatting issues, or stylistic interventions haha. I keep my compiled jasper files in the opt folder of the server that the project is running on, and access it like `opt/someFolder/report/TestPengguna.jasper`. I use jaspersoft studio app to compile and edit with [this](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-expression-editor-what-it-and-how-it-works-part-1)